# F# fsharp interop with C# library (CsvHelper)

Tags: c#, dll, f#, delegates, interop

I have been successfully using a library CsvHelper to do some CSV manipulation in F# (things that I have not been able to accomplish with Fsharp.Data CsvProvider).

In their documentation, they manipulate headers through:

```
csv.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch = header => header.Replace( " ", string.Empty );
```

I am trying to do something similar (changing all headers to lowercase), but I haven't figure out how to deal with this delegate.

I'm trying the following, but it doesn't compile.

```
csv.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch = (fun header -> header.ToLower())
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

---

I have tried @kaefer advice of assigning the "PrepareHeaderForMatch", since it is a C# getter;setter;

```
csv.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch <- fun header -> header.ToLower()
```

As noted in my comment, the compiler complaints that of a type mismatch because the c# property is expecting:

```
System.Func<System.Type, string, string>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are seeing is probably about type mismatches, or about a function type not supporting the 'equality' constraint. This is because the expression

```
csv.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch = (fun header -> header.ToLower())
```

parses as the invocation of the operator `Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators.(=)` with a property getter on the left hand side and an inline function definition on the right hand side. Instead, you want an assignment expression `expr <- expr` here, with a property setter invocation on the left hand side:

```
csv.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch <- fun header -> header.ToLower()
```

In the F# language, the `=` token is a common source of confusion, because depending on the context it can stand for two different things:

- The generic equality operator `=` as above, or
- A binding in the context of value, function, type or member definitions, for example `let x = 42`

---

**Edit** Turns out that the expected type of the property in question  is `System.Func<System.Type, string, string>`, which means that you need to supply an extra argument which you subsequently do not use. It can be represented by wildcard: `fun _ header -> header.ToLower()`

Comment: Your explanation truly helps a ton for my understanding. Yet, I still can't grasp how to match the delegate expected by the c# assembly. 

I used your suggested code, but I'm getting the following compiler error: 
-------------------------------------------------------
The type is not compatible with type System.Func<System.Type, string, string>

Comment: It's never "assignment".

Comment: @FyodorSoikin the assembly is in C# and this prop is mutable .

Comment: The last line of your answer says that the equality sign can mean an assignment as in `let x = 42`. That is _not_ an assignment.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Never is a bit strong, considering that there is a third scenario where `=` has still another use: Named arguments in a method call or to a settable property inside a constructor call. Otherwise agree and edited